# Detect sum of mulitple files using ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

**Background**
I'm using ng-file-upload to upload multiple files or file with a maximum size of 15MB. I'm managed to have my code show/hide an error when a single file over the size limit is added to the list of files. However I'm stuck on figuring out a way to have my code detect the sum of multiple files on load.

**Question**
Is there a way for me to do this cleanly in the HTML and my directive without adding too much extra functionality?

Code is Dev Environment.

**JS**

```
.directive('jobApplication', function(Upload,$location,$anchorScroll){
return{
    scope: {
        job: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/havaswwau/static/views/workforus/job-application.html',
     controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'Upload', '$location', '$anchorScroll', function($scope,  $http, Upload, $location, $anchorScroll) {

    $scope.formSubmited = false;
    $scope.submitted = false;

    $scope.submit = function(files, valid) {

        $scope.submitted = true;

        // Honeypot captcha
        if($scope.captcha !== undefined) {
            return false;
        }

        if(valid && $scope.name !== undefined && $scope.email !== undefined && $scope.tandc !== undefined){

            var jobTitle;

            if($scope.job !== undefined){
                jobTitle = $scope.job;
            }else {
                jobTitle = "Pro-Active";
            }

            if (files && files.length) {
                // Send files alongside the form data
                // check https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#-usage as a reference
                Upload.upload({
                    url: '/umbraco/api/Upload/UploadFileToServer',
                    data: {file: files, jobAppliedFor: jobTitle, name: $scope.name, email: $scope.email, tellUsAboutYourself: $scope.desc}
                }).then(function (resp) {
                    console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ' uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
                    $scope.formSubmited = true;

                    // workaround to play the checkmark animation on IE, which doesn't support strokeDashoffset CSS animation
                    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
                    {
                        var p, offset;

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            p = document.getElementsByClassName('checkmark__check');
                            offset = 48;                                    
                        },200);

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            offsetMe();
                        },400);

                        var offsetMe = function () {
                            p[0].style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
                            offset--;
                            if (offset > 0) {
                                requestAnimationFrame(offsetMe);
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        };
                    }                                

                }, function (resp) {
                    console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
                }, function (evt) {
                    $scope.progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + $scope.progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);                               
                });

            }else {

                // regular POST without any file to upload
                var data = {
                    files: "",
                    jobAppliedFor: jobTitle,
                    name: $scope.name, 
                    email: $scope.email, 
                    tellUsAboutYourself: $scope.desc
                };

                var request = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/umbraco/api/Upload/UploadFileToServer',
                    data: data,
                    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                        var formData = new FormData();
                        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                            formData.append(key, value);
                        });

                        var headers = headersGetter();
                        delete headers['Content-Type'];

                        return formData;
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    }
                };


                $http(request).success(function(data, status) {
                    $scope.formSubmited = true;
                }).error(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
        }

    };
}]
```

};
})

**HTML**

```
<div class="cbp-mc-column">

    <input id="captcha" type="text" name="captcha" ng-model="captcha" size="25" value="" />

    <input type="text" id="first_name" ng-class="{'input-error': form.first_name.$error.required && submitted}" name="first_name" placeholder="NAME" ng-model="name" ng-maxlength="80" required>

        <div class="form-errors" ng-if="form.first_name.$error.required && submitted" ng-cloak>
          This field is required.
        </div>

    <textarea id="desc" name="desc" ng-model="desc" placeholder="TELL US ABOUT YOURSELF"></textarea>            


    <div id="tandc" class="hideMobile hideTablet">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tcbox" ng-class="{'input-error': form.tandc.$error.required && submitted}" name="tandc" ng-model="tandc" required>
        <!-- <label for="tcbox">By submitting my details I agree to the <a href="/privacy-policy/" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></label> -->
        <label for="tcbox">I have read the  <a ui-sref="main.privacy" title="Privacy Policy" target="_blank">Havas Privacy Collection Statement</a> and agree to my personal information being treated in the manner stated and to receiving future communications from Havas and its promotional partners, including electronically.</label>
        <div class="clearfix form-errors privacy-error" ng-if="form.tandc.$error.required && submitted" ng-cloak>
          You need to agree with the Privacy Collection Statement to continue.
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>

<div class="cbp-mc-column">

    <input type="email" ng-class="{'input-error': (form.email.$error.required || form.email.$error.email) && submitted}" id="email" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="EMAIL" ng-minlength="6" ng-pattern="/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/" required>
        <div class="form-errors" ng-if="form.email.$error.required && submitted" ng-cloak>
          This field is required.
        </div>  
        <div class="form-errors" ng-if="form.email.$error.email && submitted" ng-cloak>
          Enter a valid email.
        </div>  

    <div ngf-select ngf-drop ng-model="files" ngf-keep="true" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-pattern="'image/*,application/pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls,.txt,.xlsx,.csv'" ngf-max-total-size="15MB" ngf-max-size="15MB" name="files" class="dropzone">                      
    </div>

    <div class="files-wrapper">
        <div class="files-refence" ng-repeat="file in files track by $index">
        {{file.name}} <div ng-click="files.splice($index, 1)" ng-show="files" class="icon icon-close-thin"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--progress  bar -->
    <div class="loading">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress_bar" ng-style="{'width': progressPercentage + '%'}" ng-show="progressPercentage >= 0">           
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix form-errors privacy-error" ng-show="form.files.$error.maxTotalSize">
          Your attachments cannot exceed 15MB.<br><br>
    </div>  
    <div class="clearfix form-errors privacy-error" ng-show="form.files.$error.maxSize">
          Your attachment cannot exceed 15MB.<br><br>
    </div>  
    <!--progress  bar end-->
    <div id="tandc" class="showMobile showTablet">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tcbox" ng-class="{'input-error': form.tandc.$error.required && submitted}" name="tandc" ng-model="tandc" required>
        <!-- <label for="tcbox">By submitting my details I agree to the <a href="/privacy-policy/" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></label> -->
        <label for="tcbox">I have read the  <a ui-sref="main.privacy" title="Privacy Policy" target="_blank">Havas Privacy Collection Statement</a> and agree to my personal information being treated in the manner stated and to receiving future communications from Havas and its promotional partners, including electronically.</label>
        <div class="clearfix form-errors privacy-error" ng-if="form.tandc.$error.required && submitted" ng-cloak>
          You need to agree with the Privacy Collection Statement to continue.<br><br>
        </div>  

    </div>

    <div class="cbp-mc-submit-wrap"><button class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" ng-click="submit(files, form.$valid)">SUBMIT <span class="icon icon-chevron-light"></span></button></div>           
</div>

 </form>

<div class="formSubmited" ng-if="formSubmited">

<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
    <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
    <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>

<div class="cvsent">APPLICATION SENT <br> THANK YOU</div>
</div>

 <a ng-if="formSubmited" href="" ui-sref="main.home" class="returnHome">
<span class="icon icon-chevron-left"></span> <span class="link-home">RETURN HOME</span>
</a>

<div ng-if="formSubmited" class="bottom-separator">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Use `ngf-total-size`

Comment: In addition to the `ngf-max-size` attribute?

Comment: Read the docs.  `ngf-total-size` is a validation for the total sum of the all file sizes.

Comment: @danial `ngf-total-size` is **not** in your [docs](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). All that is referenced is 
_ngf-min-size, ngf-max-size, ngf-max-total-size="100" in bytes or > "'10KB'" or "'10MB'" or "'10GB'"_

and

_validate as form.file.$error.maxSize=true and file.$error='maxSize' ngf-max-total-size is for multiple file select and validating the total size of all
files._

Comment: Sorry I meant `ngf-max-total-size`